# pythonnet clr how to add reference to a dll assembly?

Tags: python, .net, dll, clr, python.net

I am trying to import a dll package into python through pythonnet clr. I am aware that the package CLR and pythonnet both end up having a namespace called clr so the command "import clr" can be equivocal. Long story short, I seem to need pythonnet not the other one. I would like to be able to specify the address of the dll assembly; **this one works**:

```
import os as os
import clr
#https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#:~:text=NET%20Common%20Language%20Runtime%20(CLR,to%20embed%20Python%20into%20a%20.
import sys
Apath=os.path.normpath("C://Folder//Folder//Folder//AssemblyA.dll")
clr.AddReference(Apath)
```

but **this one fails** (got the idea of this one from [here](https://www.adrian.idv.hk/2018-08-15-pythonnet/)):

```
import os as os
import clr
#https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#:~:text=NET%20Common%20Language%20Runtime%20(CLR,to%20embed%20Python%20into%20a%20.
import sys
BfolderPath=os.path.normpath("C://Folder//Folder//Folder")
sys.path.append(BfolderPath)
clr.AddReference('AssemblyB.dll')
```

I get the following error when I try running the second one:
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'AssemblyB.dll'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)"

**this one also fails**

```
import os as os
import clr
#https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#:~:text=NET%20Common%20Language%20Runtime%20(CLR,to%20embed%20Python%20into%20a%20.
import sys
BfolderPath=os.path.normpath("C://Folder//Folder//Folder")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(Bpath)
```

"AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReferenceToFileAndPath'"

ps1. I need the second or the third way to work because I have to be sure the second assembly is not confused with another one with a similar name. 
ps2. I cannot find the documentation of pythonnet or see what kind of commands are available in my clr. Any idea?

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: In your second example: `clr.AddReference('AssemblyB.dll')` I believe when you're referencing an assembly without providing a directory to it, you use the assembly name, not the file name. Thus; `clr.AddReference('AssemblyB')` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, however, that is exactly the problem: the assembly in question has a name that is confused with another thing (a python module). This is why I need to directly add reference to the assembly by means of its full address.

Comment: Ah I see, only thing that comes to mind is to use the DLLs fullname if possible. E.g. `clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")`

Comment: thanks, finally I see something I had not tried :). Looks promising. Will report back if it worked.

Comment: Father Geppeto any outcome?

Comment: @Johannes: truth be told, I got tired of this technicality and abandoned the idea of importing that blessed dll and searched for pure python alternatives instead for the job that required those dlls.

Answer (score 1):

In second idea,

remove **.dll** from `clr.AddReference('AssemblyB.dll')` and use `clr.AddReference('AssemblyB')` because `clr.AddReference()` Requires only assembly name whether is it *.exe* of *.dll* not the folder path

That's why first idea is not working!

And for third idea `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath()` is not working because it part of **Ironpython** not **pythonnet**.

*Ironpython* is also used like *pythonnet*, but *Ironpython* is using Managed python code, while *pythonnet* is not using Managed code.