# How to use C# DLL in python (pythonnet)

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I've seen similar posts but I cannot seem to get my code to correctly work. I always get "No module named 'test'".

This is my python file:

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime
rt = get_coreclr(runtime_config="C:\\Users\\Batman\\source\\repos\\BlazorApp1\\PythonTest\\runtimeconfig.json")
set_runtime(rt)
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/Batman/source/repos/BlazorApp1/TestLibrary/bin/Debug/net6.0")
test = sys.path
clr.AddReference("TestLibrary") 
from test import TestClass
sayTest()
```

This is my C# file:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace test
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void sayTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

Both projects are located in "C:\Users\Batman\source\repos\BlazorApp1" where the Python file is in "PythonTest" and the C# file is in "TestLibrary".

The DLL is located at "C:\Users\Batman\source\repos\BlazorApp1\TestLibrary\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestLibrary.dll"

I continue to get the error "No module named 'test'"

**Additional Info**

Python version - 3.10 64-bit

Pythonnet version - 3.0.2

.NET version - 6.0.0

runtimeconfig.json:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp6.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a "module" be a class, and not a namespace? Try following these instructions exactly: https://pythonnet.github.io/pythonnet/python.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey is it not a namespace? "Python.NET allows CLR namespaces to be treated essentially as Python packages."

Comment: Well, I don't see anywhere in your code where you're referencing a .NET assembly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is my first time doing this hence why I'm seeking additional help. I thought my python about clr.AddReference was doing what you speak of. If it's not then I'd love some guidance on how to do it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Seems you're not the only one having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60617588